# How to line cross over in flowchart in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

[image]

I am drawing flow chart in draw.io, I didn't find a way cross the two lines with cross over connector as above figure. Can any one help me out?

Comment: It's not possible, currently. There is a feature request for it at https://draw.uservoice.com/forums/266072-feature-requests/suggestions/6498306-edge-bridges-jump-loops.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

as a workaround, if you need the visual element, you can create an arc as a custom shape with connection points.

It adds some extra steps to the workflow, because you have to draw lines to the connect to the arc, and then another to continue to the entity. But, you can then move the 'cross over' around and lines will stay connected.

[image: one]

after moving :

[image]

custom arc code:

```
<shape h="0.5" w="2.0" aspect="variable" strokewidth="inherit">
  <connections>
    <constraint x="0" y="1" perimeter="1"/>
    <constraint x="1" y="1" perimeter="1"/>
  </connections>
  <background>
    <path>
      <move x="0" y="0.5"/>
      <arc x="2.0" y="0.5" rx="1" ry="0.5" large-arc-flag="0" sweep-flag="1" x-axis-rotation="0"/>
    </path>
    <stroke/>
  </background>  
</shape>
```

Comment: How can you import the `<shape>` into `draw.io`. I can't find any documentation online.

Comment: The answer is by going to `Extras->Create Shape` and pasting the code provided by @dval

Comment: I was not able to use this code.

Comment: @Mindaugas you should learn harder

Answer (score 16):

Line jumps are now [natively supported](https://www.facebook.com/drawioapp/posts/1636030279754835).

When a line is selected, there is a "Line jumps" option under the style tab.

[image: line jumps]

Comment: if you're not seeing the line jump, trying bringing your line to the front using `Arrange > To Front`

Comment: Perfect answer !